# Creating custom restriction and relation between keywords and restriction

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have to create custom restriction to be applied on banner . The banner has to be visible only on specific keywords linked with that restriction.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid descriptor keywords(String):((cms2))::YRelationEnd[cms2-items.xml:52(RelationTypeTagListener)] due to missing type 'String'

Can you please help as to what might be wrong ? I have  pasted code snippets here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a relation to a "primitive" datatype like String, int or boolean. The source and the target of a relation must be itemtypes that were declared with the itemtype-tag like your WileyBannerRestriction.

I would suggest to create a keyword itemtype and link the restriction to that item. Keep in mind, that there already is an itemtype called "Keyword" present in hybris. So you need to call your keyword differently (e.g. BannerKeyword).